What is "is's" in "Mir is's gleich"?
In Wiktionary's entry for gleich I found this sentence but I am not sure how to parse it, in particular the is's part. I trying Googling it but to no avail. It seems to mean Das ist mir gleich/egal

gleich (not comparable)
all the same
Mir is's gleich. ― I don't care. (literally, “To me it is the same.”)

Also I wonder if these variations are all possible and mean the same thing:

Das ist mir gleich.
Ist mir gleich. (Can das be omitted?)
Mir ist gleich. (Does the word order matter?)
Mir gleich. (I think I have seen mir egal)


It may be worth pointing out that this is under the Bavarian entry. I'm not sure why this would be listed under Bavarian and not (Standard) German because my understanding is that this meaning occurs there as well (not to mention the other German dialects Wiktionary covers occasionally).

As a German I don't think I ever read is's. I write it ist's

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/isses

It's just "ist es". "ist" may be shortened to "is" in some dialects, "es" may be elided to become "'s", and these are being combined here.

You may add that in spoken German you do not hear this elision, it's pronounced like "Mir is' gleich", which would match one of the OP's suggested phrases, though IMHO I do not consider it as correct when written like this (it just matches it pronounciation, but the "'s" is necessary.)

Is's can of course be distinct from is': [ɪsəs], [ɪss̩] (with potential lenition of the first s). Regionally, there's isset [ɪsət].

This implies that dialect is some sort of truncated standard language, but that isn't the case. Dialects are languages in their own right, closely related to but not derived from standard language.

Mir ist gleich is wrong because that would be a shortened form of Mir ist es gleich but es can only be omitted if it is first in the sentence (in the Vorfeld).

This entry looks like it was written by someone not even remotely proficient in the dialect he described:
First off, an apostrophe signifies something left out:

Mir is's gleich

What should be left out there? Dialect is not some truncated form of standard language! There is no "left out 'e'" in Austro-Bavarian dialect, there NEVER WAS ONE IN FIRST PLACE! Yes, where in Bairisch there is "iss" there is "ist es" in standard German, but these two are different languages. E.g. when translating German "ist" to English "is" nobody would write "is'" because of the "left out -t in English" either - it never was there to begin with.
Another thing is "mir". In all Austro-Bavarian dialects I know of this is "mia", not "mir". Also, commonly a speaker of Austro-Bavarian would not use "gleich" but "wurscht". The sentence, how a native speaker would say it, would be:

Mia iss wurscht.

although the "r" in "wurscht" will only be pronounced as "r" for emphasis. Without emphasis this would come out more like "wuascht". Notice that Austro-Bavarian speakers tend to change to standard language (and back) even within a sentence for emphasis. "Gleich" could be used to put emphasis on the fact that the speaker really, totally doesn't care.
After this lengthy critizism of the entry back to standard language and to your questions:

Das ist mir gleich.

This is correct (although not dialect but standard language). You can also replace "das" by "es" and you can - because German word order is flexible - exchange subject and object too:

Es ist mir gleich.
Mir ist es gleich.

The emphasis commonly rides on the first element, so the first variant puts emphasis on the "es/das" (this I don't care for, other things I might feel differently about), the second version puts emphasis on "mir" (others might care, but I don't).

Ist mir gleich. (Can das be omitted?)

From a grammatical POV you can't, but it is common in spoken language when the subject is clear from context:

Q: Was hältst du davon?
A: Ist mir gleich!


Mir ist gleich. (Does the word order matter?)

This won't work. The left out "es/das" would occupy the first place (see example above) and this would put the Prädikat in third place. German has a liberal word order, but the "V2-rule" is strictly obeyed. This is why "ist mir gleich" works (prefixing "es" puts the Verb "ist" in second place), but "mir ist gleich" doesn't.

Mir gleich. (I think I have seen mir egal)

This is again grammatically not correct but common in spoken language. The idea is to leave out a hypothetical "es/das ist" as a prefix to this.
Spoken language has all sorts of such ommissions to speed up the talking process. Consider:

Q: What time is it?
A: seven!

A correct answer would be "it is seven o'clock", but to say only "seven" is faster and it is clear what is meant.
